# TimeMachine to USB 4TB formated apfs+ OS Mojave fails after set up

Tags: macos, timemachine

New Western Digital USB3 apfs+ format Mac OS 10.14.6 TimeMachine after preparing tries to back up 1.07 TB. gets to 3.67gb and fails. No error message
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Something to do with the Library folders. I'm having a similar outcome. A 20 GB Library folder recovers data to nearly 10TB, well tries to them fails when disk space is exhausted.